# How does fileinput.filename() work?

Tags: python, file-io, terminal

I am making a script which takes a file from terminal as an input. In order to do that I call `myScript` like that:

```
$python myScript.py <fileInput.txt
```

The script is also pretty simple:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if 'BLABLABLA' in line:
    print(line, 'THAT IS THE LINE CONTAINING BLABLABLA from the file %s' %fileinput.filename())
```

But the output is:

```
Tweedledum said BLABLABLA! THAT IS THE LINE CONTAINING BLABLABLA from the <stdin>
```

What am I doing wrong? How does the `fileinput.filename()` works? Why does it output `<stdin>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fileinput.input()` *iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty* ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)).

`<fileInput.txt` sends the contents of `fileInput.txt` to stdin. The filename won't appear in `sys.argv`, because [input redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) is handled by your shell.

If the filename contains the `<` character (or any other "special" characters), you'd quote it:

```bash
$ python myScript.py '<fileInput.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks, so is it so that it's impossible to get the filename? Or is there any trick? I've found this line: _italic_ To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file name is also allowed. I need to think a bit)))

Comment: thank you so much! I got it. So the mistake was simple))): `<` it's not a file symbol. I actually thought that I needed this symbol to put the file inside the script. After such a mod, everything works perfectly and I get the required file name =)